Error: 'CarouselController' is imported from both Package in Flutter
I tried to update my project but not able to solve this error. **I have tried using Alias - "as" keyword inside my code
import 'package:flutter_carousel_widget/flutter_carousel_widget.dart' as fcw;

    final fcw.CarouselController carouselController = fcw.CarouselController();

But now the due to package but it is working fine in their repo example app and tried using different versions of this package but getting same error.
environment:
sdk: '>=2.18.0-246.0.dev <3.0.0'
Package link - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_carousel_widget
Error :
/C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_carousel_widget-2.1.0/lib/src/helpers/flutter_carousel_options.dart:5:1: Error: 'CarouselController' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/carousel.dart' and 'package:flutter_carousel_widget/src/helpers/flutter_carousel_controller.dart'.
import 'package:flutter_carousel_widget/src/helpers/flutter_carousel_controller.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_carousel_widget-2.1.0/lib/src/_expandable_carousel_widget.dart:171:13: Error: 'CarouselController' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/carousel.dart' and 'package:flutter_carousel_widget/src/helpers/flutter_carousel_controller.dart'.
          : CarouselController() as CarouselControllerImpl;
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_carousel_widget-2.1.0/lib/src/_flutter_carousel_widget.dart:143:13: Error: 'CarouselController' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/carousel.dart' and 'package:flutter_carousel_widget/src/helpers/flutter_carousel_controller.dart'.
          : CarouselController() as CarouselControllerImpl;
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
Unsupported operation: Unsupported invalid type InvalidType(<invalid>) (InvalidType). Encountered while compiling file:///C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_carousel_widget-2.1.0/lib/src/helpers/flutter_carousel_options.dart, which contains the type: FunctionType(CarouselOptions Function({allowImplicitScrolling: bool?, aspectRatio: double?, autoPlay: bool?, autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration?, autoPlayCurve: Curve?, autoPlayInterval: Duration?, carouselController: <invalid>, clipBehavior: Clip?, disableCenter: bool?, dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior?, enableInfiniteScroll: bool?, enlargeCenterPage: bool?, enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy?, floatingIndicator: bool?, height: double?, indicatorMargin: double?, initialPage: int?, keepPage: bool?, onPageChanged: dynamic Function(int, CarouselPageChangedReason)?, onScrolled: void Function(double?)?, padEnds: bool?, pageSnapping: bool?, pageViewKey: PageStorageKey<dynamic>?, pauseAutoPlayInFiniteScroll: bool?, pauseAutoPlayOnManualNavigate: bool?, pauseAutoPlayOnTouch: bool?, physics: ScrollPhysics?, restorationId: String?, reverse: bool?, scrollBehavior: ScrollBehavior?, scrollDirection: Axis?, showIndicator: bool?, slideIndicator: SlideIndicator?, viewportFraction: double?})).
#0      ProgramCompiler._typeCompilationError (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3224)
#1      ProgramCompiler._emitType (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:3185)
#2      ProgramCompiler._emitClassSignature (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1560)
#3      ProgramCompiler._emitClassDeclaration (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:962)
#4      ProgramCompiler._emitClass (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:819)
#5      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:417)
#6      ProgramCompiler._emitLibrary (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:757)
#7      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:417)
#8      ProgramCompiler.emitModule (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:486)
#9      IncrementalJavaScriptBundler.compile (package:frontend_server/src/javascript_bundle.dart:221)
#10     FrontendCompiler.writeJavaScriptBundle (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:870)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:685)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1385)
<asynchronous suspension>
Finished with error: the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Failed to compile application.

Error is due to the package code because they have imported both package inside their file as per my knowledge due then how their example app is working
Package imports:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import'package:flutter_carousel_widget/src/helpers/flutter_carousel_state.dart';

Error
 pub.dev/flutter_carousel_widget-2.1.0/lib/src/helpers/flutter_carousel_options.dart:5:1: Error: 'CarouselController' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/carousel.dart' and 'package:flutter_carousel_widget/src/helpers/flutter_carousel_controller.dart'.
    import 'package:flutter_carousel_widget/src/helpers/flutter_carousel_controller.dart';


Yes, the error is due to package code conflicting as CarouselController is Defined in both material and flutter_carousel_widget.
I also faced the same issue and resolved it. https://github.com/nixrajput/flutter_carousel_widget/pull/47
Till new Updates are not released you can use this Repo
https://github.com/amarjeetpatidar007/flutter_carousel_widget

To resolve errors encountered after upgrading Flutter to 3.24.1, please update the carousel_slider package to version 5.0.0. This update includes a necessary name change for the CarouselController class.

This conflict happens because of the new flutter version and has added CarouselController.
Just open the package file: carousel_slider.dart and find:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

change it to:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide CarouselController;

Also, anywhere you invoke CarouselController you should hide it from material as we did above.

A new version of carousel_slider is released (5.0.0) :
[FIX] Rename CarouselController to CarouselSliderController.
If you update in pubspec.yaml to carousel_slider: 5.0.0. It should resolve the error.

This solved the problem Thanks

Use this and it will solve your problem
update package carousel_slider to version
carousel_slider: ^5.0.0

and now replace CarouselController to CarouselSliderController
ex :
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart' as cs;

final cs.CarouselSliderController _controller = cs.CarouselSliderController();


flutter_carousel_slider_plus: ^0.0.1 is another option, you just have to use CarouselControllerSlider instead of CarouselController. its totally compatible with Flutter 3.24.

I updated Flutter today and encountered an issue with a crash related to the CarouselController.
I found a temporary solution in the link below
https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider/issues/454#issuecomment-2272298820
The method is to exclude the problematic CarouselController class from the imports using the hide keyword.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide CarouselController;

I used the carousel_slider package, but I think you can solve it the same way.

I updated the carousel_slider package to version 5.0.0, which resolved the issue.

https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider   package link
